# Replace only first character from a column in a dataframe

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to replace certain words that occur at the very first of the statement in each row in the dataframe. However, passing in '1' position is replacing everything. Why is passing '1' in replace not working? Is there are different way to this?
Thanks!

## Initial:

```
df_test = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx')
print('Initial: \n',df_test)

Initial: 
                                         some_text
0   ur goal is to finish shopping for books today
1  Our goal is to finish shopping for books today
2                          The help is on the way
3        he way is clear … he is going to library
```

## Tried:

```
df_test['some_text'] = df_test['some_text'] \
        .str.replace('ur ','Our ',1) \
        .str.replace('he ','The ',1) 
print('Tried:\n',df_test)

Tried: (Incorrect Results) 
                                          some_text
0   Our goal is to finish shopping for books today
1  OOur goal is to finish shopping for books today
2                          TThe help is on the way
3        The way is clear … he is going to library
```

## Final output needed:

```
                                    some_text
0   Our goal is to finish shopping for books today
1  Our goal is to finish shopping for books today
2                          The help is on the way
3        The way is clear … he is going to library
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programming languages, including Python, don't read like human beings. You need to tell Python to split by whitespace. For example, via [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'some_text': ['ur goal is to finish shopping for books today',
                                 'Our goal is to finish shopping for books today',
                                 'The help is on the way',
                                 'he way is clear … he is going to library']})

d = {'ur': 'Our', 'he': 'The'}

df['result'] = [' '.join((d.get(i, i), j)) for i, j in df['some_text'].str.split(n=1)]

print(df)

                                        some_text  \
0   ur goal is to finish shopping for books today   
1  Our goal is to finish shopping for books today   
2                          The help is on the way   
3        he way is clear … he is going to library   

                                           result  
0  Our goal is to finish shopping for books today  
1  Our goal is to finish shopping for books today  
2                          The help is on the way  
3       The way is clear … he is going to library
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. For this case its working great. When I applied to my original data set its complaining ```ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)```

Comment: @sharp, The error's telling you need at least 2 words in your string, which makes sense if you understand the logic (`for i, j in ...`). The logic can be adapted and you can try to do this, but that's another question.

Comment: ah okay. I think there are some data issues on my side. I'll fix that. I am sure this will work. But for the case above that I posted. Your solution works well. Thanks a bunch! I spent to much time on this.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why the other answer got deleted, it was much more concise and did the job. (Sorry, I don't remember who posted it. I tried the answer and it worked but had certain limitations)

`df.some_text.str.replace('^ur','Our ').str.replace('^he','The ')`

However, as pointed out in the comments, this would replace all the starting characters starting with '`ur`' ('ursula') or '`he`' ('helen').

## The corrected code is:

```
df.some_text.str.replace('^ur\s','Our ').str.replace('^he\s','The ')
```

the '`^`' indicates start of line & should only replace the incomplete words at the beginning of line. The '`\s`' indicates a space after the first word so it only matches the correct word.

Comment: Ohh yes. I missed that.. I did introduce multiple sentences starting with 'he' though. Thanks for highlighting :) 

Tested on below dataframe:

df = pd.DataFrame({'some_text': ['ur goal is to finish shopping for books today',
                                 'Our goal is to finish shopping for books today',
                                 'The help is on the way. **he** will be here soon',
                                 'he way is clear … **he** is going to library. ']})

Comment: @jpp .. Thank you for pointing out. I've updated my answer now.